# How can I achieve this tab style in android?

Tags: android, user-interface

I'd like to know how I could achieve this effect using tabs in android. I am going to put the tab bar in a fragment so I can't use Fragment Activity.
Image: [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzCPI.jpg)
Thanks everyone for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out by using this link.
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial link using Fragments

http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant use how to I make the tab bar look in the image.